# NPM Passport Strategy LINKED Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, npm, passport.js

I have created a *custom* private passport strategy in a separate module called passport-x
I did

```
npm link .
```

in that project directory
and

```
npm link passport-x
```

in the consuming project.

In my passport.js file, I have

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var XStrategy = require('passport-X').Strategy;
..
module.exports = function(passport) {
      passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
      ....

      passport.use('x-login', new XStrategy({
      ....
```

However, I am getting this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'passport-x'
```

despite the fact I can see passport-x in my node_modules in the consuming project.

Anything perhaps I am not aware about when using more than 1 strategy at the same time or using custom strategies?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to do with the structure of the lib folder I was importing...
I had used

```
lib/
  moduleX/
       index.js
       strategy.js
```

when it was looking for an index.js in the lib directory itself:

```
lib/
    index.js
    strategy.js
```

The presence of an index.js file allows you to do this in the consuming code:

```
var XStrategy = require('passport-X').Strategy;
```